# How to set percent width of a absolute component?

Tags: css

I declare an `absolute` component inside a `relative` component. When I try to set the width as `width: 870px` it works.

But when I try to set width in per cent as `width: 80%` or using calc as `width: calc(100% - 20px);` the width does not change. Please guide me on how to use per cent for `absolute` components.

Here is my styled component code:

```
export const StyledFooter = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;

`;

export const EnrollContainer = styled.section`
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    max-width: 870px;
    padding: 80px 120px;
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
`;
```

Here is the JSX part:

```
return(
  <StyledFooter>
       <EnrollContainer>Hello</EnrollContainer>
  </StyledFooter>
)
```

Comment: Have you set the `width` of the parent?

Comment: You tagged this with `css` only, but CSS does not know anything called a "component". And neither does native HTML. So I am guessing that you are talking about something from one of those (gruesome) client-side frameworks ...? But that should not change the fact, that this is basically a HTML & CSS problem - so please provide a proper [mre] of the issue, _in_ HTML & CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set width of the parent (relative one), else it could not do a percentage on a unkown width parent

```css
#relative{
  position:relative;
  width:150px;
  border:2px solid black;
}

#absolute{
  position:absolute;
  width:50%;
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="relative">
  <div id="absolute"></div>
</div>
```